# Лишняя строка при обращении к БД

Tags: mysql

Всем доброго времени. Суть вопроса такова : есть 2 таблицы - первая: Куплено и  вторая: Продано.

Обе таблицы строятся по принципу : одна покупка/продажа= 1 строка.

В Таблице покупок указаны : `Type`,`Date`,`Title`, `Count`, `Magazinnumber`.
В таблице проданного : `Title`, `Count`, `Magazinnumber`. На самом деле много чего еще, например `ID` каждой покупки/продажи но к сути не относится.

Нужно выбрать из **Куплено** товары с **одинаковым** названием , просуммировать их количество .... Затем выбрать из **Продано** товары с теми же самыми названиями- - --> просуммировать количество проданного и вычесть первое из второго для нужного магазина. Иначе говоря получить множество строчек с **ТЕКУЩИМ** количеством каждого товара, сгруппированного по названию в магазине. Запрос выглядит :

```
SELECT `Type`, `Date`, `Title`, COALESCE(SUM(col1),0)-COALESCE(SUM(col2),0)
FROM(
SELECT  `Type`,`Date`,`Title`, `Count`  AS col1, NULL AS col2
FROM `byutable` WHERE MagasinMumber= 'es3354' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,0,`Title`, NULL AS col1, `Count` AS col2
FROM `saletable` WHERE MagasinMumber = 'es3354'
) X
GROUP BY `Title`
```

выполняя такой запрос я получаю правильный результат : несколько строк в которых указаны типы товаров, их имена и текущее количество **в магазине es3354**. Но мне нужно не все типы товаров в этом магазине а только один определенный. Казалось бы достаточно добавить еще одно условие после where вот так :

```
FROM `byutable` WHERE MagasinMumber= 'es3354' AND TYPE = 'Milk'
```

Но тогда в запрос попадает еще одна строчка, в которой записано количество проданного : минус "-100" или "-1". Как от неё избавиться ?

Comment: Вам надо такое же условие добавлять и ко второй выборке, из saletable

Comment: @Mike спасибо вам добрый человек! Разобрался.можете ответить на вопрос, тогда я защитаю вам +1 ответ.